# Changing Shimano 105 triple chainset to compact

Tags: shimano, chainring

I'm looking to buy a used 2015 Cube Agree GTC Race. The only drawback is that it has a triple chainset, and I would prefer a compact. Which parts might I have to replace apart from the chainset itself?

Comment: If you like the bike, buy it and ride it.  Take on some steep hills and learn to love the triple.  They're not trendy, but climbing is about gearing, and its definitely trendy to pass the haters while climbing!

Answer (score 2):

To go from a triple to a compact, you generally need to switch the front derailleur for one for doubles (make sure it can be attached to your frame and the right cable pull; front derailleurs have different cage shapes between doubles and triples), the front shifter (if indexed; you need a double shifter rather than a triple shifter, and it needs to have compatible cable pull with the front derailleur) and if you're using a bottom bracket with a spindle (like a standard JIS/ISO bottom bracket, Octalink, etc.), you may need to have a different spindle length (to get the right chainline). And of course, you need the compact crankset (which is compatible with your bottom bracket).

In your case, you have a hollowtech II bottom bracket (with a Shimano road group), so you need:

- Compact Crankset which fits hollowtech II bottom brackets (reasonably common; Shimano, FSA, etc. make them)
- Shimano road double FD (cheap; you can get tiagra or higher for only 20-50 USD)
- Shimano road double shifters (Expensive; you only need front shifter for a double, but you may end up getting  a set in which case you need to match the rear number of speeds as well).

I'd suggest trying the triple for a while -- you may end up liking it despite it not being in vogue.